# how to disable caching of filter results in jinja2

Tags: python, pyramid, jinja2

We are working on a Pyramid (with Jinja2 templates through pyramid_jinja2) application that gives user his unique subdomain and a way to change this subdomain to any other available subdomain later.

So, for example, you can go to sub.example.com/settings and change your subdomain to "dub". After submitting this change you are redirected to dub.example.com/settings.

We have one issue with this setup - because our subdomain is stored in request object and we have custom pregenerators for every subdomain-based view - when we call route_url while we are on sub.example.com - the result seems to be cached and the same url is generated when we change our subdomain. So for example after the subdomain change (until we restart our application) we are on the site with dub.example.com address, but some links (menu, "action" targets in some forms) have still "sub.example.com" in the url, because this url was generated before subdomain change.

I have a problem finding on what level the generated url is cached and all in all - I have no good idea how to avoid it. Disabling cache of url generation is less then perfect (though I didn't even know it was "a thing" until now).

What is in your opinion best way of working out that kind of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time to debug this issue, but created a patch for pyramid_jinja2. See https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_jinja2/pull/74.

The filter is being evaluated as const, (function as_const in nodes.py of jinja2), causing the filter to only being executed once.